# Problems with Ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox (Lenovo IdeaPad 330 i5)

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

0

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox on my windows laptop. 7 out of 10 times when I boot my virtual machine I run into these frequent issues:

- YouTube or any other video/audio streaming keeps loading, then plays for a second and again starts loading.
- I use a bluetooth earphone which works fine on my windows PC but when I use it in my Ubuntu VM, the latency is so high that it is barely usable.
- Sometimes when I disconnect my earphone, the audio gets stuck and 1 or 2 seconds of audio keeps looping (like old DVD players) and I have to restart the VM.

**Permanent Issues**

Frame rate at which YouTube videos play is visibly low as compared to when I play them on windows on the same machine.

Double tap on touchpad works for same cases and doesn't work for some.

I am new to Linux and don't have much idea of how to fix these issues. I have already installed the codecs using this command `sudo apt-get install Ubuntu-restricted-extras` but it doesn't fix these issues.

I really like this OS and want to stick to it but with these issues its really painful.